# The `fork()` system call returns two values to parent and child process?

Tags: c, linux, unix, system-calls

In the book "Operating System Concepts" I found such a context:

> In UNIX , as we’ve seen, each process is identified by its process identifier, which is a unique integer. A new process is created by the fork() system call. The new process consists of a copy of the address space of the original process. This mechanism allows the parent process to communicate easily with its child process. Both processes (the parent and the child) continue execution at the instruction after the fork() , with one difference: the return code for the fork() is zero for the new (child) process, whereas the (nonzero) process identifier of the child is returned to the parent.

It confuses me. Sounds like that the same `fork()` function returns two different values to both of the parent and the child process? How can that be possible (one function returns two different values to two processes), or did I misunderstand it?

Comment: You're misreading. It returns one value in the parent, one value in the child. But those two values are different.

Comment: In the parent it returns the PID of the new child. In the child it returns 0.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your reply. But isn't a system call a function? Then how can a function returns two values to two processes? This is my confusion.

Comment: It's only returning ONE value in each process.

Comment: @Barmar So there are two calls for the `fork()`? One in the parent process and one in the child process?

Comment: Here's an analogy. Someone puts you into a cloning booth, it creates a duplicate of you. The two of you walk out of the booth, and the operator hands a red apple to the original, a green apple to the clone. Those apples are the return values.

Comment: Yes `fork` is a function. It's a function that goes all the way down into the operating system kernel. The kernel will create a new process, and set up the context in it so that  it seems that the single call to `fork` returns in both the old and the new process.

Comment: There is one call to fork and it returns twice to the original caller and to the newly created child process.

Comment: No, only _one_ call. You start with _one_ process: the "parent". The _kernel_ creates a _second_ process (the child). It will start/resume _both_ processes. But, it sets the return value of the child to zero and the parent to the [new] pid of the child. This is kernel "magic" if you will.

Comment: The difference is so that, _after_ the `fork`, your program knows whether it is the parent process or child process. A typical usage: `pid_t pid = fork();  /* child -- invoke program */ if (pid == 0) { execl("/usr/bin/echo","hello world",NULL); perror("execl"); exit(9); }  /* parent -- wait for child to complete */ else waitpid(pid,NULL,0);`

Comment: I think I understand it now. Just some double check: the kernel creates a new child process, and this process is a copy of the parent process, including the call for `fork()`. Then this child process and its parent process are like two concurrent processes and got different returned values from the `fork()` call. Is that correct?

Comment: Now you're getting it! :)

Comment: Yes, more or less. The kernel [exactly] duplicates the parent's memory mapping, memory data, open file descriptors, and processor registers (etc) into a separate copy for the child. The _only_ [discernable] difference is the return register value (e.g. on intel/x86, it is the `%eax` register). `%eax` gets 0 in the child and the pid number in the parent. Otherwise, it's practically impossible to discern which is which (_without_ further system calls).

Comment: See also: `setjmp()`

Comment: Make sure to accept the best answer by clicking the check mark next to it so we know you are all set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter `fork`, there's only a single process. While inside `fork`, this single process is cloned/copied. Now there are *two processes* running *the same code* in parallel. Both processes are still inside the `fork` function. Eventually, each process will exit the `fork` function: the parent process will exit the fork function (returning the PID of the child) and the child process will exit the fork function (returning 0).

Fork (ASCII art):

```
                   ,-- (parent process) child PID returned to parent
parent -- fork() --
                   `-- (child process)  0 returned to child
```

Fork (clip art):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code that demonstrate the behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    printf("parent: %ld\n", (long) getpid());
    pid_t p = fork();
    if(p) {
        printf("parent: %ld, child: %ld\n", (long) getpid(), (long) p);
        pid_t p2 = wait(&(int) {0});
        printf("parent: p == p2? %d\n", p == p2);
    } else {
        printf("child: %ld\n", getpid());
    }
}
```

and example session:

```
parent: 76693
parent: 76693, child: 76694
child: 76694
parent: p == p2? 1
```

The initial (parent) process (76693) calls `fork()` which creates a new child process (76694).  The process id of the child is returned to the parent in it's variable `p`.  The value `0` is returned to the child process in it's variable `p` which is distinct from the parent's variable `p` (even if they have the same virtual address). For good measure, the parent waits for child to exit and verifies that we got the expected child process id.